Узнать, является @username пользователем или каналом (pyrogram)
Все написал в вопросе. Как через pyrogram по данному юзернейму узнать, принадлежит он обычному пользователю или каналу/группе? пролистал всю документацию, но ничего не нашел по этому поводу.
